# Python: string encoding that keeps German special characters and decodes \x84

Tags: python, string, text, encoding, rtf

I'm currently working with some transcripts of interviews. My goal is to read in these transcripts to later perform some Natural Language Processing tasks on them. The transcripts are in german and the transcripts are .rtf files. I use the  `rtf_to_text` function from [`striprtf`](https://github.com/joshy/striprtf) to read in the transcripts. The output is a string object.

This actually works quite well - however in some transcripts characters are not decoded properly, see for example:

```
Out: "Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig \x84du\x93 sagen."
```

The original text would read:

```
"Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig "du" sagen."
```

Is there a way to decode this properly while keeping the German special characters such as "Ä"?

If I do an `.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii")` I loose the \x84 and \x93 and all German special characters as well.

Comment: `.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii")` gives _UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)_. What should be the purpose of this? Are you sure that the string `"Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig \x84du\x93 sagen."` means that is is not correctly decoded? `\x84` just means that there is a character with the hex value 84 at that position. Try evaluating `x[26]` (where x is the variable holding your string). It should print the single character '\x84'

Comment: UTF8 and codepages in general are character to byte mappings, they don't have escape sequences. Python 3 strings are Unicode and the the text was successfully converted. `\x84` is an escape sequence in the RTF file that wasn't converted by `striprtf`. This is an RTF problem, not an encoding problem

Comment: This is a bug in `striprtf`. Until it's fixed, you may be able to replace such escape sequences after calling `striprtf` using simple text replacement

Comment: Super helpful, thank you!

Comment: It's _latin1_ (try yourself). `'Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig \x84du\x93 sagen.'. encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')` returns `'Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig „du“ sagen.'` (note _different_ quotes around the word _du_).

Comment: Ah, thank you - this works for this transcript! 
Unfortunately, these transcripts seem to come from different machines with different configurations so that different characters are not decoded properly. 

I'm now trying to find all examples of \x  using `re.findall()`. I'm currently struggling with correctly escaping the \x . Tried different numbers of  \   before the  \x 
as well as ` re.escape("\x" )` and `r""` strings. If you could point me in the right direction with this problem, I'd be super thankful!

PS: I seem to run into similiar problems when writing this comment

Answer (score 1):

Your string character set is [ISO/IEC 8859-1 (`latin1`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Try yourself:

```
'Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig \x84du\x93 sagen.'.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')
```

> ```
> 'Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig „du“ sagen.'
> ```

and vice versa:

```
'Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig „du“ sagen.'.encode('cp1252').decode('latin1')
```

> ```
> 'Ähm, [..} du kannst ruhig \x84du\x93 sagen.'
> ```

Note different quotes around the word *du*. They are (column `CodePoint` contains Unicode (`U+hhhh`) and UTF-8 bytes):

```
Char CodePoint                               Category Description
---- ---------                               -------- -----------
   „ {U+201E, 0xE2,0x80,0x9E}         OpenPunctuation Double Low-9 Quotation Mark
   d {U+0064, 0x64}                   LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter D
   u {U+0075, 0x75}                   LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter U
   “ {U+201C, 0xE2,0x80,0x9C} InitialQuotePunctuation Left Double Quotation Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no encoding in which Ä retains its Unicode code point (I'm guessing the input had `\xe4`?) while the bytes `\x84` and `\x93` mean something else.

Probably the proper fix is to figure out what encoding the original RTF is using and *correctly* decode that at the time when you are parsing the RTF file.

https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#84 shows a number of encodings in which `\x84` decodes to the Unicode code point [U+201E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201E/); except for `cp874` the same ones have the expected encoding for `\x93`. Comparing with `\xe4` reduces the set with the expected encodings to `cp1250`, `cp1252`, `cp1254`, `cp1257`, `cp1258`, and `palmos`. If you have additional data points, you can probably narrow this down further ... Or just wager a bet that the input encoding is probably `cp1252` which is the common Windows default scourge^Wcode page in Western Europe.

(Disclaimer: That's a page I created, once upon a time.)